# Merging two XML files on a key field

Tags: json, xml, vb.net

Let's say I have the following two XML files with the following structure:

```
<supervisors>
     <supervisor id="1">
         <firstName>John</firstName>
         <lastName>Smith</lastName>
         <department>IT</department>
     </supervisor>
     <supervisor id="2">
         <firstName>Jack</firstName>
         <lastName>Jones</lastName>
         <department>HR</department>
     </supervisor>
     <supervisor id="3">
         <firstName>Allan</firstName>
         <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
         <department>Sales</department>
     </supervisor>
     <supervisor id="4">
         <firstName>Chris</firstName>
         <lastName>Reyes</lastName>
         <department>Shipping</department>
     </supervisor>
</supervisors>

<employees>   
     <employee supervisorID="1" employeeID="2">
         <firstName>Mike</firstName>
         <lastName>Albert</lastName>
         <phone>1111111111</phone>
     </employee>
     <employee supervisorID="1" employeeID="3">
         <firstName>Alicia</firstName>
         <lastName>James</lastName>
         <phone>1112222222</phone>
     </employee>
     <employee supervisorID="3" employeeID="4">
         <firstName>Anne</firstName>
         <lastName>Thomas</lastName>
         <phone>1112223333</phone>
     </employee>
</employees>
```

I want to wind up with a dataset that looks like this JSON (it can be an actual dataset, but for this I am showing JSON because it is easier to represent):

```
[
     {empFName: "Mike", empLName: "Albert", supFName: "John", supLName: "Smith", dept: "IT"}, 
     {empFName: "Alicia", empLName: "James", supFName: "John", supLName: "Smith", dept: "IT"}, 
     {empFName: "Anne", empLName: "Thomas", supFName: "Allan", supLName: "Johnson", dept: "Sales"}
 ]
```

How do I combine the XML data to properly return the way the JSON above is returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384460.aspx) makes this easy, and [XML literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) make it beautiful (if you are in to that sort of thing) - LINQPad example:

```vb
Dim supervisors = 
<supervisors>
     <supervisor id="1">
         <firstName>John</firstName>
         <lastName>Smith</lastName>
         <department>IT</department>
     </supervisor>
     <supervisor id="2">
         <firstName>Jack</firstName>
         <lastName>Jones</lastName>
         <department>HR</department>
     </supervisor>
     <supervisor id="3">
         <firstName>Allan</firstName>
         <lastName>Johnson</lastName>
         <department>Sales</department>
     </supervisor>
     <supervisor id="4">
         <firstName>Chris</firstName>
         <lastName>Reyes</lastName>
         <department>Shipping</department>
     </supervisor>
</supervisors>

Dim employees =
<employees>   
     <employee supervisorID="1" employeeID="2">
         <firstName>Mike</firstName>
         <lastName>Albert</lastName>
         <phone>1111111111</phone>
     </employee>
     <employee supervisorID="1" employeeID="3">
         <firstName>Alicia</firstName>
         <lastName>James</lastName>
         <phone>1112222222</phone>
     </employee>
     <employee supervisorID="3" employeeID="4">
         <firstName>Anne</firstName>
         <lastName>Thomas</lastName>
         <phone>1112223333</phone>
     </employee>
</employees>

Dim joined = (
    From e In employees.<employee>
    Join s In supervisors.<supervisor> On e.@supervisorID Equals s.@id
    Select New With {
        .empFName = e.<firstName>.Value,
        .empLName = e.<lastName>.Value,
        .supFName = s.<firstName>.Value,
        .supLName = s.<lastName>.Value,
        .dept = s.<department>.Value
    }
)

joined.Dump()
```

This results in:

[image: LINQPad output]

[Json.NET](http://www.json.net/) can convert that to JSON.

```
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(joined)
json.Dump()
```

```
[
    {"empFName":"Mike","empLName":"Albert","supFName":"John","supLName":"Smith","dept":"IT"},
    {"empFName":"Alicia","empLName":"James","supFName":"John","supLName":"Smith","dept":"IT"},
    {"empFName":"Anne","empLName":"Thomas","supFName":"Allan","supLName":"Johnson","dept":"Sales"}
]
```